# User doesnt save to database Django

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
def registerPage(request):
        form = UserCreateForm()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form=UserCreateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user=form.save(commit=False)
                user.save()
                return redirect('home')
        return render(request,'base/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,null=True)
    bio=models.TextField(null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['username']
```

forms.py

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name','email','password1','password2','bio','avatar']
```

htmltemplate

```
{%  include 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{field.label}}
            {{field}}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Register" >
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

when ever i try to sign up on html template it doesnt work but if i do it in admin panel it works how can i solve it ?

Comment: can you show us the template also?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is generally not recommended to mess with the default `User` model from django. Its better to create a `Profile` model with a `OneToOneField` relationship with the user.

Other than that, your issue lies with your form. Since you have `avatar` which is an `ImageField` you need to change your form in a way that it can accept `FILES`.

So what you need to do is change your form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

> When you are writing client-side code:
>
> - use multipart/form-data when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.

In order to make your `POST request` valid, you need to also receive your `FILES` on your view. That can be done by changing your code to:

```
 if request.method=='POST':
            form=UserCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
            ....
```